# <script> $('#timepicker1').timepicki(); </script> in body tag not working after button click which is placed inside updatepanel

Tags: jquery, timepicker

Initially after the page load when i click in the timer control text box, time pop up appears, but Timer control is not working after clicking the save button which is inside the updatepanel. Pls help..

In aspx page:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="timePicker.aspx.cs" Inherits="timePicker" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="Timepicki is a light weight jQuery Time Picker plugin for using in form submission websites.">
    <meta name="keywords" content="timepicki, timepicker, time, jquery, plugins">

    <title>Workings</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/timepicker/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="css/timepicker/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/timepicker/timepicki.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="script1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upd" runat="server">
            <ContentTemplate>
                <table border="1">
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <input id="timepicker1" type="text" style="width: 80px" runat="server" name="timepicker1" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <label>
                                Enter Text</label>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="txtText" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine">
                            </asp:TextBox>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <asp:Button ID="btnSave" CssClass="btn-success" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
    </div>
    <!-- For Timepicker -->
    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->

    <script src="js/timepicker/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/timepicker/timepicki.js"></script>

    <script>
        $('#timepicker1').timepicki();
    </script>

    <script src="js/timepicker/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <!-- End For Timepicker -->    
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

In code behind: For inserting the values in table

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            string strID = "";

            if (txtText.Text.Trim() == "")
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "Msg", "<script language='javascript'>alert('Remarks cannot be empty!')</script>", false);
                return;
            }

            strID = objD.GetSequence("T_TEST", "TEST", "TID");

            objD.sQry = "";
            objD.sQry += "INSERT INTO T_TEST(TID,TDESC,CRE_DATE,CRE_USER,STATUS) VALUES('" + strID + "','" + txtText.Text.Trim().Replace("'", "''").ToString() + "',SYSDATE,'TEST USER','L')";
            int iAdd = objD.InsertSQL();

            //btnSendAuth.Enabled = true;
            Response.Redirect("Default.aspx?qVal=" + strID);
        }

    }
```

Comment: "Not working" is just a little too vague to help. Any errors in the console? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

First problem is that you're calling the timepicker, before loading Bootstrap.
Second problem is that you're running it before the DOM is rendered. 
Third problem is that you had a typo, it should be `timepicker`,instead of `timepicki`.

This should work:

```
<script src="js/timepicker/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/timepicker/timepicki.js"></script>
<script src="js/timepicker/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#timepicker1').timepicker();
    });
</script>


<!-- End For Timepicker -->
```